# Trying to use function argument to declare array size is throwing an error

Tags: c++

What have I done wrong? The error I'm receiving is saying that I can't use bWidth and bHeight to set the size of the array unless they're constant, but I very much need them to be variable. Have I formatted this poorly?

```
int random_state(int bWidth, int bHeight) {



int board_state[bWidth][bHeight];

for (int i = 0; i <= bWidth * bHeight; i++) {

    srand(time(NULL));

    int randomOut = rand() % 2 - 1;

    board_state[i][i] = randomOut;
    cout << board_state[i][i];

}


cout << "Test";
```

}
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d82lR.png)

Comment: either look at dynamic arrays or (if you can) use std::vector

Comment: `int random_state(int bWidth, int bHeight) {

    

    int* board_state = NULL;
    int n1, n2;
    n1 = bWidth;
    n2 = bHeight;
    board_state = new int[n1][n2];

    for (int fi = 0; fi <= n1 && fi <= n2; fi++) {

        board_state[fi] = 0;

    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= bWidth * bHeight; i++) {

        srand(time(NULL));

        int randomOut = rand() % 2 - 1;

        board_state[i][i] = randomOut;
        cout << board_state[i][i];

    }


    cout << "Test";


}`

I'm encountering the same issue as before, but now only with n2.

Comment: If you absolutely need a 2d plain c array https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new

Comment: keep in mind you'll have to write a similar loop to delete each row afterwards- 
You could also use a 1d array and pretend its a 2d array by manually calculating the offset